# Array Index Out Of Bounds Exception -77

Tags: java, python, arrays, exception, byte

I've a little problem with my code.
I tried to rewrite code from python to java.

In Python it's:

```
data = bytearray(filesize)
f.readinto(data)
```

Then I tried to write it in java like this:

```
try {
        data = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Encrypter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    for(int index : data) {
        data[index] = (byte) ((byte) Math.pow(data[index], genfun((fileSize), index)) & 0xFF);
    }
```

Everything seems to be good for me but when I compile it and there is an java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -77

Has anyone have a clue or can rewrite it better?

Comment: `for(int index : data)` Why do you think that you can get indices by using this? This is wrong. Use a regular `for` loop instead.

Comment: @Tom This is a pretty rude way of telling him that he's using incorrect syntax. @czaro112112 use the `for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)` format to iterate over an incrementing index. Your current syntax iterates over the values of `data`

Comment: @Kon You mean *"This is a pretty rude way of telling him that he's using obviously incorrect syntax which would have been known by using a few minutes of research."*? I really struggle to understand why a lot of new users don't do research on used API or syntax. It's disappointing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `for` loop of this form (an "enhanced" for loop) yields the *values* of the array, not the indexes.  The value `-77` was the signed value of the `byte`, not the index, hence the exception.  Note that even though the value was extracted as a `byte`, Java was all too happy to widen `value` implicitly to an `int` as you declared it.

Use a standard `for` loop:

```
for (int index = 0; index < data.length; index++)
{
    byte value = data[index];
    data[index] = (byte) ( /* Your byte manipulation of value goes here */ );
}
```

Comment: As the asker of this question, at your discretion, you may [accept exactly one answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) that you think answers the question the best.

Answer (score 1):

Java's `for (a : b)` loop loops over *values*, not indices.

`index` is not actually an index.